# DynamicProxy2: CreateClassProxyWithTarget + IInterceptor

Tags: c#, castle-dynamicproxy, iinterceptor

If I've missed this in another question I apologize; I looked for a good while before deciding I had a unique question... I want to use DynamicProxy2 to provide interception for a WPF application's model classes.  This is so that I do not have to fully implement INotifyPropertyChanged everywhere.  For instance, the below class should fully participate in two-way data binding once proxied and intercepted:

```
public class ModelExample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Uri{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

I have found that I can create a new instance of the model class and intercept calls to it by calling the CreateClassProxy method:

```
new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxy<T>(interceptors);
```

Unfortunately, this forces me to allow the `ProxyGenerator` class to create my model instances, and I'm getting those back from my middle tier, i.e. they already exist.  I need to wrap existing objects, so I **think** I need to call `CreateClassProxyWithTarget` instead:

```
new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxyWithTarget(instance, interceptors);
```

However, when I do that my interceptor stops functioning.  I'm pretty sure it's not the interceptor's fault... it's a very simple object.  Here's its interface:

```
public interface IFluentInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    IFluentInterceptor Before(Action<IInvocation> before);
    IFluentInterceptor After(Action<IInvocation> after);
    IFluentInterceptor Finally(Action<IInvocation> @finally);
    IFluentInterceptor RunCondition(Func<IInvocation, bool> runCondition);
    IFluentInterceptor OnError(Func<IInvocation, Exception, bool> onError);
}
```

The `FluentInterceptor` type implements this.  The `Before`, `After`, etc. methods are too simple to show; they all add to action queues that are meant to be used during method invocation, then each method returns `this`, allowing for method chaining.

The below code doesn't work, but I can't figure out why:

```
new ProxyGenerator().CreateClassProxyWithTarget(instance, new FluentInterceptor()
    .After(invocation =>
    {
        if (!invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_")) return;
        string propertyName = invocation.Method.Name.Substring(4);
        FieldInfo info = invocation.TargetType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .Where(f => f.FieldType.Equals(typeof (PropertyChangedEventHandler)))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (info == null) return;
        var handler = info.GetValue(invocation.InvocationTarget) as PropertyChangedEventHandler;
        if (handler != null) handler.Invoke(invocation.TargetType, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }));
```

If I try that with `CreateClassProxy`, it works like a charm.  Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I think this is a non-issue. If I ever need a container to generate the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation for me, it'll probably be in fringe cases where I'm plugging in model objects that get built by the container anyway because they have depedencies, etc. In those cases `CreateClassProxy<T>(interceptors)` is fine. In all other cases I have been using MVVM ViewModels where the exact logic surrounding change notification is decided on a case-by-case basis, with the user experience being the focus. Model classes usually get flattened or transformed in some way, so the whole point is moot. I asked this question at a time when I didn't understand how to properly leverage MVVM in my app, and I thought I was going to be responsible for more moving parts. It's actually been a lot easier than anticipated, once I started configuring my ViewModels properly.